# LWC OSS utilising SLDS

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

I have seen the other questions on this subject and can either inject the slds stylesheet into my component, or use the synthetic DOM. Using either approach, SLDS styling is generally working ok.

However, there are instances when the SLDS utilises pseudo elements `:first-child` and `:last-child` which kind of breaks things a little. To illustrate the issue, take the setup assistant which comprises of an ordered list:

```html
<ol class="slds-setup-assistant">
  <li class="slds-setup-assistant__item">
    <article class="slds-setup-assistant__step">
      <div class="slds-setup-assistant__step-summary">
        <div class="slds-media">
          <div class="slds-setup-assistant__step-summary-content slds-media__body">
            <h3 class="slds-setup-assistant__step-summary-title slds-text-heading_small">Add Users to Your Org</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-media__figure slds-media__figure_reverse">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand">Add Users</button>
            <p class="slds-text-align_right slds-text-color_weak slds-p-top_medium">4 mins</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </li>
</ol>
```

and styling (from slds):

```css
.slds-setup-assistant__item {
  border-bottom: 1px #dddbda solid;
  padding: 2rem 0; 
}
.slds-setup-assistant__item:first-child {
  padding-top: 0; 
}
.slds-setup-assistant__item:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0; 
}
```

> Renders correctly with the right spacing and bottom border:
>
> [image]

However, when I convert `li.slds-setup-assistant__item` to a component, I end up with:

```html
<ol class="slds-setup-assistant">
    <c-setup-assistant-item id="item1">
       <li class="slds-setup-assistant__item">
          <!-- content removed for brevity -->
       </li>
    </c-setup-assistant-item>
    <c-setup-assistant-item id="item2">
       <li class="slds-setup-assistant__item">
          <!-- content removed for brevity -->
       </li>
    </c-setup-assistant-item>
</ol>
```

Which of course means that the `li.slds-setup-assistant__item` is always the `:first-child` and the `:last-child` because its the only child of `c-setup-assistant-item` rather than being a direct descendant of the `<ol>`. I realise the whole point of web components is isolation and mixing top level stylesheets is not the done thing, but I want to avoid hacking the SLDS since css is not particularly my strong point. Has anyone come up with an elegant solution for this?

Comment: how did you get Salesforce font on your component? Mine renders in Arial by default

Comment: I can't remember exactly, do you have a stylesheet link to the slds stylesheet in your index.html? e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css" type="text/css" >`

Comment: I used <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SLDS/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/> and it solved the issue. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out - funny how asking a question often leads you to the answer. The trick was to override the SLDS css with something more specific, e.g.

```css
c-setup-assistant-item>li.slds-setup-assistant__item {
    border-bottom: 1px #dddbda solid!important;
    padding: 2rem 0!important; 
}

c-setup-assistant-item:first-child>li.slds-setup-assistant__item {
    padding-top: 0!important; 
}

c-setup-assistant-item:last-child>li.slds-setup-assistant__item {
    padding-bottom: 0!important;
    border-bottom: 0!important; 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer.

Comment: When lwc moves to a full web components implementation, will this be possible? (at the moment, the DOM is not fully isolated, I believe)

Comment: In my question, I stated that I was using the Synthetic DOM as opposed to the Shadow DOM. If it were using Shadow DOM, this approach would not be possible I don't think. The solution feels like a bit of a hack tbh, but not sure what the alternative is if I want to use SLDS and not reverse engineer the whole .css file